# Power automate: Calculate date and write to column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, date-time

I'm solving such a problem and I don't know how to proceed.

I have a list in which the documentation information is stored.

The columns of the list are: Document name, document type (option 1, option 2) and a column valid until in which to write the following.

If a new entry is added with document type option 1, then add 365 days and save the value. If the document type is option 2, then add 720 days and also store the value in the column valid until.

Comment: "document type" is of type Choice or Single line of text?

Comment: Choice, but I can convert to sigle line or lookup.If that helps. Thanks

Comment: Choice column is fine, check my answer given below. It should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use flow like this:

[image]

**Expressions used**:

**Condition action** (left hand side):

```
@triggerOutputs()?['body/DocumentType/Value']
```

Where `DocumentType` is an internal name of your choice column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Set variable action**:

```
@{addDays(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'],365)}
```

**Set variable 2 action**:

```
@{addDays(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'],720)}
```

**Output**:

[image]